# Templates and cyclic dependency

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I have the following architecture problem leading to a cyclic dependency of headers. It involved generic programming and C++ templates. So:

- I have defined properties which are aggregated in nodes
- These properties are defined as templates
- One of the arguments of this template is the familly of the data type handled by the property
- There is a specialization of the Property template for each family of types:

  - basic types (float, int...)
  - pointer to a node
- The family of the data type is computed using meta-programming

  - basic types -> template argument = 0
  - pointer to a node -> template argument = 1
  - unhandled type -> template argument = -1
- My cyclic dependency is related to type family "pointers to nodes"

  - In order to determine whether the pointer's type is a node I have compile-time code which checks whether class ConcreteNode derives from class Node
  - Though to determine this the compiler needs to know the declaration of ConcreteNode
  - Hence I have to include ConcreteNode's header when a property containing a pointer to ConcretNode is defined rather than simply forward declaring ConcreteNode
- This causes problems if ConcreteNodeA contains a pointer to ConcreteNodeB and inversly ConcreteNodeB contains a pointer to ConcreteNodeA

  - I this case I need to include the header of ConcreteNodeB in the header of ConcreteNodeA, and inversly
  - This causes a cyclic dependency of headers

Here is a bit of code to illustrate all this:

```
// Property.hpp
class PropertyBase
{
    // Some code common to all properties.
}

template <class T, int typeFamily = TypeFamily<T>::value >
class Property : public PropertyBase
{
    // Default template to catch errors.
};

template <class T>
class Property<T, 0> : public PropertyBase
{
    // Data is a base type.
    T* m_dataRef;

    // Some basic types-specific stuff.
};

template <class T> 
class Property<T*, 1> : public PropertyBase
{
    // Data is a pointer to a concrete node.
    T** m_dataRef;

    // Some pointer to node-specific stuff.
}; 


// ConcreteNodeA.h
#include "ConcreteNodeB"

class ConcreteNodeA : public Node
{
protected:
    Property<ConcreteNodeB*>& m_nodeB;
};


// ConcreteNodeB.h
#include "ConcreteNodeA"

class ConcreteNodeB : public Node
{
protected:
    Property<ConcreteNodeA*>& m_nodeA;
};
```

Obviously my real code is more complex than this:

- i.e. the base type is only handled if it is part of a list of handled types
- I did not expose the meta-code used to determine if a class derives of another one

  - I guess people willing to help me know about it
  - And people who do not should not be encumbered by it

Anyone has an idea of how I can declare my properties without getting this cyclic dependency  problem? At the moment I am stuck...

Thanks!

----- EDIT ------

The following

```
TypeFamily<T>::value
```

is meta code which returns 0 if T is a supported base type, 1 if T is a pointer to a class deriving from a node, and -1 in other cases.

----- EDIT ------

I cannot use forward declaration for ConcreteNodeA and ConcreteNodeB because in this case, the compiler has no way to "understand" ConcreteNodeA and ConcreteNodeB derive from Node. And thus TypeFamily::value will return -1, not 1. Hence the selected templated will be the default "catch-errors" one, not the one I want (typeFamily == 1).

----- EDIT ------

`Node` knows about `Property`, as it aggregates them. It looks like this:

```
#include "Property.hpp" // This file also contains the declaration for PropertyBase.

class Node
{
private:
    std::vector<PropertyBase*> m_props;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to include the header of `ConcreteNodeA` to use a pointer to a `ConcreteNodeA`, you just need to forward declare `ConcreteNodeA`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, if I forward declare my classes ConcreteNodeA and ConcreteNodeB, the compiler has no mean to know that these concrete classes derive from class Node. Thus the compiler uses the default "catch-errors" template rather than the one for pointers to nodes.

Comment: If you forward declare the Concrete classes rather than include them, TypeFamily<T>::value will return -1, not 1. Hence the selected templated will be the default "catch-errors" one.

Comment: Please give a short, self-contained, example of the the problem.  Your question is too general as it stands right now to demonstrate the specific problem you are facing.

Comment: Hey Vaughn, I have updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Use forward declarations instead:

ConcreteNodeA.h:

```
class ConcreteNodeB;

class ConcreteNodeA : public Node
{
protected:
    Property<ConcreteNodeB*>& m_nodeB;
};
```

ConcreteNodeB.h:

```
class ConcreteNodeA;

class ConcreteNodeB : public Node
{
protected:
    Property<ConcreteNodeA*>& m_nodeA;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, if I forward declare my classes ConcreteNodeA and ConcreteNodeB, the compiler has no mean to know that these concrete classes derive from class Node. Thus the compiler uses the default "catch-errors" template rather than the one for pointers to nodes.

Comment: If you forward declare the Concrete classes rather than include them, TypeFamily<T>::value will return -1, not 1. Hence the selected templated will be the default "catch-errors" one.

Answer (score 2):

Like every problem in computer science, this can be solved by adding another layer of indirection. The crux of the problem is that the type trait that determines the second default argument for `Property` requires the type of the first argument to be complete. If that type is incomplete, you can't even declare a pointer or reference to `Property` which otherwise doesn't require `Property` itself to even be complete. The solution is to delay the analysis of `T` by the type trait until instantiation time by introducing a middle layer class `PropertyImplementation`:

```
template <class T, int typeFamily = TypeFamily<T>::value >
class PropertyImplementation : public PropertyBase
{
    // Default template to catch errors.
};

template <class T>
class PropertyImplementation<T, 0> : public PropertyBase
{
    // Data is a base type.
    T* m_dataRef;

    // Some basic types-specific stuff.
};

template <class T>
class PropertyImplementation<T*, 1> : public PropertyBase
{
    // Data is a pointer to a concrete node.
    T** m_dataRef;

    // Some pointer to node-specific stuff.
};

template <class T>
class Property : public PropertyImplementation<T> {};
```

Now you can declare `Property` with an incomplete type as its parameter, indeed you can even forward declare `Property` itself:

```
// ConcreteNodeB.hpp

#include "Node.hpp"

class ConcreteNodeA;
template <class> class Property;

class ConcreteNodeB : public Node
{
protected:
    Property<ConcreteNodeA*>& m_nodeA;
};
```

`Property` and `ConcreteNodeA` need not be complete until the compiler needs to instantiate them. If you need them to be complete, e.g. so you can use `m_nodeA` in inline declarations in ConcreteNodeB.hpp, then you can include Property.hpp anytime and ConcreteNodeA.hpp *after* the ConcreteNodeB class declaration.

Comment: Hum interesting. When I deploy this solution I have an error with an operator= I have redefined in the Properties. So I'll sort this out first and I ll be able to come back to you in a few hours...

Comment: I am not able to reproduce exactly the same situation you describe: header of `Node` includes `Property.hpp` and so I cannot forward declare template `Property` in `ConcreteNodeB.hpp`. So I introduced the distinction between `PropertyImplementation` and `Property` and forward declare `ConcreteNodeA` and with this only, the compiler still complains as it cannot instantiate the relevant specialization. I have edited my initial post to give more details about the relation between `Node` and `Property`.

Comment: @arennuit Neither `Node` nor anything in the `Property` hierarchy have any dependencies on the `ConcreteNodeX`, this should have no effect. [See sample code here, which embodies all the dependencies that you have described herein](https://github.com/cartec/arennuit).